# Фрагмент кода работает не так, как ожидалось

Tags: поддержка, сниппеты

Почему код во фрагменте кода ниже, который должен вывести

```
[ a: 2 ]
```

выводит

```
[]
```

```js
const arr = [];
arr['a'] = 2;
console.log(arr);
```

как добиться желаемого вывода

Comment: твоя ошибка в том, что код ниже **не должен** выводить `[ a: 2 ]`. Чтобы это заработало, замени `[]` в строке `const arr = [];` на `{}`

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Не, это на самом деле к реализации `console` в сниппете относится

Comment: @Grundy не понял связи, мой фаерфокс тоже ведь `[]` выводит

Comment: @andreymal, в сниппет подключается скрипт, который переопределяет объект _console_, и при вызове log, error и т.д. добавляет непосредственно в разметку див с выводом. Внутри себя для вывода этот код использует `JSON.stringify`, который, для массивов проходится **только** по числовым свойствам, так как `a` - это не числовое свойство, оно отсутствует в выводе, а так как других свойств нет - выводится пустой массив.

Comment: @Grundy, ответ пиши тогда уж.

Comment: @Qwertiy, забавно, оказывается внутри не `JSON.stringify` использовался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для отображения [консоли в сниппете используется сторонний скрипт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets).

Внутри этого скрипта переопределяется ряд методов объекта `console`.

В новой реализации параметр переданный в функцию переводится в строку. Перевод осуществляется кодом, основанном на [Douglas Crockford's json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Конкретно за перевод массива отвечает код

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') {

    length = value.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        partial[i] = str(i, value) || 'null';
    }

    v = partial.length === 0
        ? '[]'
        : '[\n' + gap + anchor + "\n" + gap + partial.join(',\n' + gap) + '\n' + mind + ']';
    gap = mind;
    return v;
}
```

Из него видно, что проход осуществляется **только** по числовым индексам.

Поэтому в случае из вопроса, когда в массиве нет числовых индексов, результат верный: пустой массив. Это также соответствует стандартному выводу при применении к этому массиву функции `JSON.stringify`.